# Using DOM Buttons in dojox.mobile

Tags: dojox.mobile

I have a question on the DOM Buttons technique explained by Yoshiroh Kamiyama in this Article :-

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/library/mo-dojo-mobile-performance/index.html

Where can I find documentation on the various DOM button classes that I can use ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any explicit documentation on this, but you can run the dojox/mobile/tests/test_domButtons.html test case that shows the available DOM buttons classes.